# SQL Server : how to set a comparison based on the middle of variable date

Tags: sql, sql-server, bi-publisher

I have a variable date and I need to be able to check if the date before the 15th then print "beginning of the month" and if the date is after the 15th then print "end of the month"

The date is formatted as '2021-11-08T00:00:00.000-05:00' and this can be any date and this is just an example.

`SuspensionDate` is the variable

- if SuspensionDate is anything before the 15th then print the beginning of the month
- if SuspensionDate is anything after the 15th then print end of the month

Please advise
Thanks,

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(day, SuspensionDate) >= 15 THEN 'end' ELSE 'beginning' END + ' OF THE MONTH'` maybe

Comment: What if the date *is* the 15th?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the suggestions mentioned above.

I was able to get to the right method that works with oracle db.

This is what I used in case nay benefits anyone else.

CASE WHEN (EXTRACT (DAY from tcn.UXSUSPENSIONENDDATEDOP)) > 15 THEN 'end' ELSE 'beginning' END suspensionday

Answer (score 0):

Here is some functionality that should get you where you need

Get beginning of month
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @mydate), 0) AS StartOfMonth
Get Day of date
SELECT DAY('2017/08/25') AS DayOfMonth;
Get end of month
SELECT DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @date) + 1, 0))

Comment: Thank you for your reply, these functions didn't work with oracle DB, they work with sql server though but it led me in the right direction.